# md5.sum and sha512.sum recursive checksum mismatch

Tags: gcc, download, release, checksum

I was just downloading the latest stable gcc release from [here](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/gnu/mirror/gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-7.1.0/).

The md5.sum covers the sha512.sum file and vice versa. But when I check the sha512 checksums, I get an error regarding the md5.sum:

```
➜  gcc LC_ALL=En_US sha512sum -c sha512.sum 
gcc-7.1.0.tar.bz2: OK
gcc-7.1.0.tar.gz: OK
md5.sum: FAILED
sha512sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

Checking with md5 works just fine, but ... you know ... md5

It seems logical that there is an error. After all, how should both files contain the checksum of each other without breaking at least one of the hash functions. I am a little bit puzzled, though. What is the purpose of listing the md5.sum file in the sha512.sum in the first place?